# Multiple collision bitmasks on 1 physics object?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, bit-masks

Can one physics body have 2 different collision bit masks?

I have this code:

```
         bo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noneCategory
```

But I'd like "bo" to also collide with "bumperCategory".  So, I imagine it could look something like this:

```
        bo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noneCategory && bumperCategory
```

That doesn't work.  Is there anyway to do something similar to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you need to bitwise OR instead of logical AND the two categories:

```
bo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = noneCategory | bumperCategory
```